# Menu and breadcrumbs

Tags: routes, breadcrumbs

I need the menu bar and breadcrumbs to use different hierarchies. Specifically, I need the menu bar to have:

`Home | Projects | About | Contact`

but I need the breadcrumbs for a project page to be:

`Home > Projects > Project title`

In "Content > [Projects page] > Edit > Menu settings > Parent item", to get "Projects" to show up in the menu bar, I have to set the parent to "<Main menu>". But if I do that then the breadcrumbs on a project page become:

`Projects > Project title`

so I lose "Home" in the breadcrumbs.

So the question is, how do I get "Projects" to be in the menu, but allow it to be under "Home" in the breadcrumbs?

I see there are lots of contributed modules for managing menus and breadcrumbs, but I wonder if there's something readily available in core that I don't know about. If not, what is the right module to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello. I'm not in shape to write a real answer, but have you played with [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)? I think it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is defining custom breadcrumbs for your Project content type:

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs

Comment: Seems I was faster by 10 seconds ;) Could you expand your answer? I honestly don't know now how to define Custom Breadcrumbs in a way that would really answer OP's question. That's why I only  posted a comment.

Comment: The README.txt file in the module is quite thorough. You can configure custom breadcrumbs for different types of nodes. You can hard-code a crumb, like "Home" or you can use tokens to create dynamic crumbs.